# Удаленное обновление sqlite таблицы

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Сейчас обновляю бд на компьютере, через db_version и бд, логично, меняется только при установке. Бд находиться в папке assets. Мне необходим метод, который удаленно на всех устройствах с моим приложением, заменять бд более новой. Но вот никак информацию не могу в интернете найти. Подскажите, как сделать.

Comment: удаленно никак, единственный на мой взгляд вариант - на сервер забросить бд и оттуда брать, а это уже совсем другая история :)

Comment: Так и сделал. Поместил БД на Firebase Storage и оттуда скачивал в папку files, заменяя предыдущую.

Answer (score 3):

Стандартных средств для такой задачи нет.

Обычно действуют так:

Приложение поставляется как есть. После, при необходимости, выпускается обновление, которое при следующем запуске выполняет нужные команды для изменения схемы/добавления данных в БД. Таким образом, последняя версия БД будет у юзеров с последней версией приложения.

Если же вам надо управлять схемой БД и/или её содержимым удалённо, то тут всё сложнее.

1. В любом случае нужно место в интернете, которое будет содержать всё необходимое для обновления схемы/добавления данных.
2. Приложение же, по расписанию или по пушу, например, должно сходить на сервер и получить инструкции и данные для обновления. Например скрипты миграции схемы + команды для вставки данных.
3. Для внесения любых изменений таким образом в приложении надо написать код, который будет выполнять полученные с сервера инструкции. Т.е. оно должно уметь выполнять произвольную строку как SQL команды.

Самый простой вариант, который не потребует собственного сервера - размещать команды публично (хоть в посте в ВК/Facebook) и получать их приложением по расписанию.

Самый сложный - собственный сервер, оповещающий приложение о необходимости изменений через пуши.